# liquid form layout with display:inline-block

Tags: css, forms, liquid

I have got a form with label container and value container in one row and i have made a fiddle to illustrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/eEvEN/3/

The layout is fixed and i never want the value container to wrap under the label container. Since both containers are set to `inline-block` i can do `white-space:nowrap` to the list row (see fiddle) and the goal is partially acomplished. 
Partially, because in the value container i do want the text to wrap if the browser is not wide enough to hold the text in one line. 
So i thought i could do `white-space:normal` to the value container, but it dosn't work... and it reimains in `nowrap` fashion.

What can i do to make this work alright?

Comment: have you tried using!important on the white-space:normal ?

Comment: thx, but try it yourself, it doesnt work.

Comment: also, I have made a typo. I have meant to write that the layout is fluid, not fixed! sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it using CSS table display (i.e. **table-row** and **table-cell**).
But this solution will [misbehave in older IE versions](http://caniuse.com/css-table).

```
li {
    display: table-row;
}
.field_label {
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 140px;
    background: yellow;
}
.field_widget {
    display: table-cell;
    background: cyan;
}
```

Solution using CSS tables http://jsfiddle.net/ECssv/

Solution using HTML tables http://jsfiddle.net/VrHMm/ should work in older IEs

Comment: yeah, tried that too and it doesn't work only in IE7 and down.
It is a good solution, although i have been looking one for IE7 just in case too. 
It's probably the one i will use.

Comment: you can change the HTML and replace List (UL LI) with Table (TR TD). Then you'll get support for IE7 ;)

Comment: tables are pita for customization, when you never know if some rows won't have more or less cells than usual. There are so many other cons and pros, that one could write an article about it ;]